# Adding WinForms in a WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I created a WPF project. The requirement initially was to have a XAML based UI but later on it got shifted to Windows Forms. As I had all my business logic already in that WPF application, I started adding **Windows Forms** and deleted the XAML file except **App.XAML**.

I just want to know how to make it a totally WinForms based project? What to do with **App.XAML** file and how to set up the Start page?

The **App.XAML.CS** looks like this

```
<Application x:Class="Mold_Power_Suite.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="/View/FormAbout.cs">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My Folder Structure Looks Like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What all things you got on App.XAML?

Comment: App Xaml is just setting your start page and nothing else. You just have to set your start page in your winfrom application.

Comment: how shall I do that ? Can i delete this App.XAML file ?

Comment: @CarbineCoder I will post the screenshot. The code was a VB WinForms code which has been converted to C#. Please check and assist

Comment: The comments about "start page" make no sense. A Winform project doesn't have a "start page". It's not too hard to create from scratch the elements needed for a Winform project: you'll need to remove the WPF/XAML stuff, and add a `Program.cs`, with a `Main()` method that has the `[STAThread]` attribute and the usual boilerplate (you can copy from an empty Winforms project). But I don't understand why you don't just create a new empty Winforms project and copy your existing forms over to that. It would be the simplest way. Please explain what _specifically_ you're having trouble with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have an old VB based WinForms project which I was converting to C#. As far as I see that under the project properties->Application->"Application Type" is mentioned as "Windows Forms Application" and there is an option of "Startup Form" set to a selected from as well as "Splash Screen" option. How to set these in the converted C# app?

Comment: The options you describe are not available in a C# project. They are specific to the VB.NET project type. They are also different from what you'd see in a WPF/XAML project, unless that project was also VB.NET (that has a "Startup URI" option). If you want help with VB.NET project, you should remove the [tag:c#] tag and add the [tag:vb.net] tag. In any case, it's still not clear why you want to do all this rather than just create a fresh C# project and add the existing source code to that project. That's a lot simpler than trying to manually duplicate the project template VS provides.

Comment: @PeterDuniho shall I add a program.cs file and set the startup location as one of the forms I need ?

Comment: _"set the startup location"_ -- I guess that depends on what you mean by that. As I said, a C# project doesn't have a project setting controlling that. But you can specify whatever initial form you want in the `Program.cs` file, assuming you've put all the correct Winform boilerplate there. Since I have no way to know what your project looks like, I can't say for sure what you need to do. As I said before, I would just start over with a new project; it's trivial to move your existing code to a new project, and doing it that way will ensure all the project settings and code is exactly right.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I will paste the screenshot of my project in the question. I have created folders and inside the View folder I have all my Form.cs .

Comment: @PeterDuniho updated. Please see the screenshots and the last one has App.XAML that needs to be deleted. If you suggest , I can add a Program.cs file and then can set the startup form -the same one on which VB solution is pointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not even sure how you got this to run, `StartupUri="/View/FormAbout.cs"` doesn't work for me.

But conversion is real simple, all you need is a `static void Main()` to do your `Application.Run(new MainForm());`.

You probably already have one, do a Ctrl+Shift+F search if you're not sure.

To resolve any confusion, you can mark the class with Application.Run as the startup object in Project|Properties.

After that runs you can start to remove all XAML files and the Presentation*.DLL references.

Have an empty WinForms project in a scrap folder standby to compare anything.

Comment: I have deleted the App.Xaml and created a Program.cs in which I added the form i wanted to run. The form is loading but none of the buttons are working. even the close button present on the top right is not closing the window

Comment: Make sure you have only one Application.Run .

Comment: how can I access Designer for the VB based WinForms application ? I copied and pasted the UI elements of VB forms to C# forms and it seems that none of the events like click and load are working

Comment: Create a new WinForms project, add a button with an event  and make sure you know how everything works. Study the .Designer.cs file and its comments.

Comment: do we have a designer file for VB project ?

Comment: Create a new VB project and find out... You may want to check the Show All Files button.